# Formatting in Pentaho Interactive Reporting

Tags: formatting, reporting, pentaho, interactive

I have a field in my domain as Fiscal Year which is created as a Numeric field. Because of that, when I try to pull that column I am getting the data in the below format,

`2,017`

Which I don't want. I need to remove that comma and display in that report.

Please let me know whether there are any options to specify the formatting in interactive report or can I morph the column to Date field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the metadata editor, you can add a property called "Mask for Number or Date". In that property field, you can create a mask of "####" to prevent the comma in your numeric data.